# Is my webapi project still dependent on the data access layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

When using dependency injection, which module holds the interface?

For example, if I have a webapi service project and a data access layer project does that mean I put the definitions for IUnitOfWork, IRepository, etc in the webapi project, and put the UnitOfWork, Repository, etc classes that implement those interfaces in the data access project?

Second, if I'm using a NinjectConfigurator class that contains all my bindings and I place it in my webapi project so it's initialized on startup, doesn't that mean my webapi project is now dependent on the data access layer since the Bind functions have to know about types defined in the data access layer?

eg.

```
private void AddBindings(IKernel container) {
    container.Bind<myDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    container.Bind<IUnitOfWork<myDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<myDbContext>>();
    container.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Ninject needs interfaces to be mapped to implementations. I'm using Ninject to perform dependency injection in my webapi project. Since Ninject needs to be configured before use, and the AddBindings function is inside my webapi project, doesn't that mean my webapi project is dependent (or knows about) all the concrete implementations that are mapped to those interfaces? If so, we haven't solved any problems. I still need to recompile my webapi if there's a change made to UnitOfWork.

Answer (score 0):

A best practice is:

1. Domain Layer (Entities, Interfaces for Repositories and Services)
2. Data Layer (Repositories)
3. IoC Layer (Ninject and all modules)
4. Presentation Layer (Web Project)

Your binds will be in the IoC layer, and on your web project you just call the Modules.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load(new DomainModules(), new DataModules(), new CrossCuttingModule(), new ServiceModules());        
}
```